# how to create sublists in a loop in R

Tags: r, list, loops, nested-loops

I have a for loop inside of a while loop.
After each while iteration I increment with 1 (count = 1 then count = 2 ...)
With each for iteration I return several variables.(a = 1, b = 2)

I want to create a list with count = 1..4, then each for iteration(i) and then with the variables that I create in the for loop. Examples:

```
List$Count1$Iter1$a

List$Count2$Iter2$a

List$Count4$Iter3$b
```

In the example below I want a list called "out" with :
`out$(W_count)1...4$(Iter)1...5$A,B`

I know that the code has several problems but I can't find the proper way of approaching this problem.

```
count = 1
while( count < 5 ) {

    for(i in 1:5) {
        b = i * i
        a = b * 2
        out = list(W_count = count)
        out[[count]] = list(iter = i)
        out[[count]][[i]] = list(A = a, B = b)
        count = count + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear to me what you are trying to do. Can you show input as well as expected output for the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly,

```
out <- list()
count = 1
while( count < 5 ) {

    for(i in 1:5) {
        b = i * i
        a = b * 2

      out[[paste0("W_count",count)]][[paste0("Iter",i)]] <-list(A = a, B = b)

    }
    count = count + 1
}
```

gives,

```
> out$W_count1$Iter1$A
[1] 2

> out$W_count2$Iter2$A
[1] 8

> out$W_count4$Iter3$B
[1] 9
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Such a simple process and I was confusing it so much. Thanks a lot